# Keras binary classification accuracy stuck at 50%

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm using keras in R to build a cats/dogs binary classifier and using a dataset of 3000 samples (1500 cats, 1500 dogs, split 9:1 training/testing). With each epoch my classification accuracy does not rise over 50%.

Would appreciate any help as to what could be going wrong. I have triple checked my testing and training directories and `split/testing/Cat/` contains 150 cat images, `split/testing/Dog/` contains 150 dog images, `split/training/Cat/` contains 1350 cat images, and `split/training/Dog/` contains 1350 dog images. This is my first time using keras and running a CNN image classifier so I would appreciate any advice.

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, 
     kernel_size = c(3,3), 
     activation = "relu", 
     input_shape = c(256, 256, 3)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, 
     kernel_size = c(3,3), 
     activation = "relu", 
     input_shape = c(256, 256, 3)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") %>%
  compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
          loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
          metrics = c("accuracy"))

datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(directory = "split/training/",
   generator = datagen, 
   target_size = c(256, 256), 
   classes = c("Cat","Dog"), 
   class_mode = "binary", 
   batch_size = 32)
test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(directory = "split/testing/",
   generator = datagen, 
   target_size = c(256, 256), 
   classes = c("Cat","Dog"), 
   class_mode = "binary", 
   batch_size = 32)

model %>% fit_generator(generator = train_generator, 
   steps_per_epoch = as.integer(train_generator$n / 32), 
   epochs = 5, 
   verbose = 1, 
   validation_data = test_generator)
```

My model looks like this:

```
> summary(model)
Model: "sequential_11"
______________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                       Output Shape                   Param #     
==============================================================================
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)                 (None, 254, 254, 32)           896         
______________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 127, 127, 32)           0           
______________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)                 (None, 125, 125, 32)           9248        
______________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 62, 62, 32)             0           
______________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)                (None, 62, 62, 32)             0           
______________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)                (None, 123008)                 0           
______________________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)                   (None, 256)                    31490304    
______________________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)                   (None, 1)                      257         
==============================================================================
Total params: 31,500,705
Trainable params: 31,500,705
Non-trainable params: 0
______________________________________________________________________________
```

And my epoch summaries look like this:

```
> model %>% fit_generator(generator = train_generator, steps_per_epoch = as.integer(train_generator$n / 32), epochs = 5, verbose = 1, validation_data = test_generator)
Found 2700 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 300 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/5
84/84 [==============================] - 83s 984ms/step - loss: 7.5916 - accuracy: 0.4974 - val_loss: 7.5069 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/5
84/84 [==============================] - 82s 977ms/step - loss: 7.6703 - accuracy: 0.5004 - val_loss: 7.8263 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/5
84/84 [==============================] - 83s 984ms/step - loss: 7.7310 - accuracy: 0.4970 - val_loss: 7.8263 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: Dropout should not be used by default - only if you have issues with possible overfitting.

Comment: Update - I increased batch size to 128 and the model started performing well (75% validation accuracy within 10 epochs). Playing around with the parameters helped.